# Magento - cannot add stored procedure using install script

Tags: magento-enterprise, install-script

I have created a **stored procedure** which do some updates in database. Now when I am trying to add that stored procedure using **magento install script** from `sql` folder, It is not being updated..

I cannot see stored procedure created in database.. I am using below syntax there

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->query(STORED_PROCEDURE_SYNTAX);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all. I got solution from another stackoverflow comment

Now I have used syntax as below.

```
$sql = <<< __SQLPRC
STORED_PROCEDURE
__SQLPRC;
```

and run it using

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->exec($sql);
```

and it is working fine now

Comment: Does the `.sql` file not work in your scenario?  (Which imo sounds like the better way of running SQL code)

Comment: I have not tried it as now I got solution using php file. But will try that in future

Comment: I would recommend looking over [This article by Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) to understand how set-up resources work and i'm then sure you can create a `install-X.X.X.sql` to run the SQL syntax directly as your solution is a long winded way of the same thing.